# How to get data from a web application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-applications

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am new to this.

I am getting started with iPhone application development and would like to create an application that involves pulling data from a web service.

Let's say the URL is `http://myapp.com/api/people/fetchall` and it returns XML data.

- How do I get this data into my iPhone App?

**Update:** After doing some research I decided that (on the Server-side) I want to implement a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) that returns JSON. So my iPhone application will ultimately be a REST client.

### Resources:

Here are some links that I have found helpful so far:

- [RestConnection - accessing RESTful web services from the iPhone](http://www.dreamfreeze.net/weblog/restful_webservices.html)
- [Creating RESTful Web Service Clients in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch](http://developer.apple.com/safari/articles/creatingrestfulclients.html)

Comment: This question is a bit overloaded. You've already identified the individual questions you're really asking (ie, you know how to "break the problem down"), but it's best to post these individually on SO. You can actually answer the last question by reading the docs (well-covered topic). The rest make good individual SO questions.

Comment: This question is way too broad, as there are different reasons to go with different choices. How much data? Are you persisting it for later? What kind of data? etc. I would suggest you start with the NSXMLParser, try an implementation, then come back and ask more specific questions as you encounter them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you've already broken down the main points, which is a good start.

Firstly, the web application will need its API to return data in a format that can be parsed easily by clients, whether they be iPhone apps or anything else. For this reason, a lot of web apps use JSON or XML. HTML is not a good format for transferring data, HTML is good for marking up text to be presented.

So firstly, write your web app to return XML or JSON formatted responses. If you have the time, you can make your web app do both, and specify as a parameter which format you want the response to be in.

To get the data down from the web app to your iPhone app, you're going to need to make a URL connection and download the data from one of your API calls.

For instance, if your API has a method that will return some information about a user, you'll need to build up an http request in your iPhone client, and send it to the server via the API URL, specifying whether it is a GET or PUT or other type of http request.

Interesting classes to look at for this are `NSURLRequest` and it's mutable counterpart and `NSURLConnection` and it's delegate protocol, `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

Parsing the data will depend what format it is in. For XML, you can use the XML parser that is available in the iPhone SDK, `NSXMLParser`.

If you're going to be using JSON, you can use one of the JSON parsing libraries available on the iPhone. Personally, I've used [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/) and [JSON-Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

To populate the table view, you will need to implement a couple of methods from the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, and a few from `UITableViewDelegate`. Reading up on the documentation for the `UITableView` class and the aforementioned protocols should give you enough information to start using them.

I hope this helps and gives you a starting point to learn more.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo originally. I meant to say "I assume XML is easier to work with"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Three20](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/) project—the developer of the Facebook iPhone app, Joe Hewitt, made a lot of his work open-source, including a table-view class that can populate itself with data from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple... 
here are few links to get you started
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

this tutorial will tell u how to make necessary changes in your plist file and how to tell your app to launch from URL. Secondly, then the code needs to be done in the method in your app delegate class named as :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

from the url...get all the information u need and call the JSON web service from this. An example to call JSON is here:

```
[[AFCoVuAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"whatever.json"
                                         parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:loginSessionKey forKey:@"login_session_key"]
                                            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                NSLog(@"Did logout successfully on app termination");

                                                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; //End the task so the system knows that you are done with what you need to perform
                                                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; //Invalidate the background_task
                                            }
                                            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Did NOT logout successfully on app termination");
                                            }];
```

and u can save the data in ur singleton class

where ur AFCovuAPIClient class .h file looks like

```
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface AFCoVuAPIClient : AFHTTPClient    

+(AFCoVuAPIClient *)sharedClient;

@end
```

and AFCOvuAPIClient.m file looks like this
    #import "AFCoVuAPIClient.h"

```
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@implementation AFCoVuAPIClient

+(AFCoVuAPIClient *)sharedClient {
static AFCoVuAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
_sharedClient = [[AFCoVuAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url goes here"]];
});

return _sharedClient;
}

-(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
if (!self) {
    return nil;
}

[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

return self;
}

@end
```

hope this helps